# How to produce a different md5 hash with different encodings?

Tags: php, vb.net

I am porting over some code from .net (vb) to php and I came across some md5 hashing that I can't reproduce in php. In the .net one there are two functions one uses UTF-8 encoding and the other uses Unicode encoding. The output is a different hash when passed in a string

```
// First function (returns GUID)
Dim oHasher As Cryptography.MD5 = Cryptography.MD5.Create()
Dim oEncoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
Dim csData() As Byte

csData = oHasher.ComputeHash(oEncoder.GetBytes(strInput))


// Second function (returns GUID)
Dim oHasher As Cryptography.MD5 = Cryptography.MD5.Create()
Dim oEncoder As New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()
Dim csData() As Byte

csData = oHasher.ComputeHash(oEncoder.GetBytes(strInput))
```

In php I have tried using

```
$passHash = md5(utf8_encode($password));
$newPassHash =  md5($password);
```

but they both produce the same result. Is it possible to produce the same results in php with md5 hashing?

Answer (score 1):

Unicode can be implemented by different character encodings. The most commonly used encoding is UTF-8, but I wonder what `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()` is using by default.

Try using UTF-16, as it's the only real likely alternative to UTF-8 in this scenario.

You can use [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to move between different character encodings, and it supports UTF-16.

Comment: UTF-16 would be a safe bet on Windows.

Comment: I keep getting a different result for both utf-8 and utf-16. I'm using the following   $passHash = md5(utf8_encode($password));
                $newPassHash = md5(mb_convert_encoding($password, "UTF-16"));

Comment: That's what I'd expect - as you're hashing different sequences of bytes.  Does the utf-16 hash match the Windows UnicodeEncoding() hash?

Comment: no. I need to convert the string to a byte array and then hash that array. Any idea how to do that in php? NOne of the hashses are currently working

Answer (score 1):

Answer is on: http://technikq.blogspot.de/2013/09/php-utf-16-hashed-md5-string.html

Basically:

```
$string = "e3e3_e37";
$stringEncoded = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
$encoded_string = md5($string);
```